# Using Hotkeys Api and use switch method to switch between the Shortcuts in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I try to use Hotkey Api file as in this blog [Hotkey Api](https://community.sap.com/t5/technology-blogs-by-members/hotkeys-keyboard-shortcuts-in-sap-ui5-using-open-source-plugin/ba-p/13316483) Hotkey Api and have some questions. First Api file called Hotkey.js. How can I call the hotkeys which are located in this file in controller file to use it there?

second question: should I use switch method instead of using if condition each time and to make the code more tidy? And how to use switch method hier?

Thank you

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgM9S.png)

[image: image2]
[image: image3]

```
var table = this.byId("table");
        table.addEventDelegate({
            onkeydown: function(oEvent) {
                var selectedCheckbox = false;
                var items = table.getItems();

                // Check if any checkbox is selected
                for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                    var checkbox = items[i].getCells()[0]; // Assuming the checkbox is in the first column
                    if (checkbox.getSelected()) {
                        selectedCheckbox = true;
                        break;

                    }

                }
                // Execute the code only if a checkbox is selected
                if (selectedCheckbox) {
                    if (oEvent.keyCode === 46) {
                        this.onRemoveRowsUi();

                    }
                    if (oEvent.ctrlKey || oEvent.metaKey) {
                        if (oEvent.code === "KeyC") { // Check if the pressed key is 'C'
                            this.onCopyPress();
                        }
                        if (oEvent.code === "KeyV") {
                            this.onPastePress();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }.bind(this)
        });
```

Comment: Since SAP UI5 1.70 you can use a standard mechanism to use shortcut in your App : 
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/entity/sap.ui.core.CommandExecution

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you know where can I find more examples and explenation?